# Finding height of binary search tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, binary-search-trees

> Suppose given a binary search tree $T$ with $n$ nodes with depth $h$.
> We did $n$ times search with cost $c_i$ for search $i^{th}$ search on
> $T$ ,and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i=O(n\log n)$. what we can say about $h$?

I think $h=O(\log n)$, but instructor say it's not true.

Comment: Hints: 1) If you have a branch of height $h$, what's the total time required for searching each node in this branch? 2) Based on the previous item, what is the maximum value of $h^*$ (in $O$-notation) so that the total search time for the branch of height $h^*$ is $O(n \log n)$? 3) Now, create a tree where almost all heights are $O(\log n)$ and there is one branch of height $h^*$.

Comment: Right. To make such a tree, 1) build a complete binary tree with $n$ nodes. 2) extend one of its branches: from height $O(\log n)$ to height $O(\sqrt{n \log n})$. 3) The number of nodes is $O(n + \sqrt{n \log n}) = O(n)$, which should be good enough. If you want to make the number of nodes to be exactly $n$, simply remove some lower-height nodes.